# Ubuntu 11.10 fresh install in VirtualBox won't boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, 11.10, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu on a VM in VirtualBox but after the installation Ubuntu won't boot up at all! It is stuck at a black screen which is doing nothing.

What happened during installation and how do I fix this? Installation took over 3 hours and I don't want to wait another 3 hours for another installation!

Comment: i'm going with network latency and the update during install option.  dialup and updating most of the distro would make this happen on initial install time.  make sure those options aren't checked and see if it doesn't go a lot faster.  VM specs would be helpful too

Answer (score 1):

Probably your system is not enough to install ubuntu in vm

burn  iso file into cd or usbstick
and try it

if you want to install ubuntu as vm you  may need to upgrade your system and provide enough ram and other settings

Comment: Typical installation of ubuntu takes 15 to 30 minutes only